# Trouble with Acquia Dev Desktop post-install step

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, acquia

I am learning Drupal and have to use it for an upcoming project. When I try to install Acquia Dev Desktop, I get an error message:

```
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. For assistance, please finish the installation and post a new forum message to bit.ly/dd-bugs with these files: C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop/installer.log C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop/piscript.log
```

This makes me unable to run Dev Desktop. The only error messages I have noticed in those files are:

```
Running post install script. This may take a couple of minutes.
Executing C:\Program Files (x86) \DevDesktop\common\setup\postInstallPhp.cmd "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\common\setup\setup.php"
Script exit code: unknown signal

Script output:


Script stderr:
 child killed: unknown signal
```

Answer (score 2):

according to the Acquia blog, download an older version - https://dev.acquia.com/downloads/releases/devdesktop.

> "Issues with Windows and most recent release of Acquia Dev Desktop We
>   are investigating an issue with the latest version of Acquia Dev
>   Desktop and Windows. At this time, Acquia recommends that Windows
>   users experiencing errors with the most recent release revert to a
>   previous release."

Rgds,